# Is it possible to transfer the save data of COD BO2 from a PS3 to an Xbox One S?

Tags: ps3, xbox-one, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I'm planning to buy an Xbox One S and continue playing Black Ops 2, but I don't know how to transfer my save data from my PS3 to an Xbox One S.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately saves are formatted for the console on which they are created.  Microsoft and Sony use completely different formats.  It is not possible to move a save between console lines.